Input/ Output Impedance of Converter/Input Filter (SIMPLIS)
I'm trying to replicate an impedance plot showing the output impedance of the upstream filter and the input impedance of the downstream converter, but within the sample plot.
Can I get help with:

Setting Up the filter impedance circuit and getting the correct gain/phase diagram
Making the filter output impedance and converter input impedance appear on the same plot

Below is my converter input impedance plot at max load and minimum input voltage

My attempt at doing the filter impedance circuit and plot... The plot clearly isn't showing anything within the gain plot, so, then I'm clearly not understanding something...

EDIT - May have found how to do it :)
Okay, does this the plot and circuit look like I've implemented this correctly? fyi, the mag/phase plot is of the filter alone. This is believable to me because the LC resonant frequency if you remove all the parasitic (that I just estimated) looks correct. The second resonant frequency shift also moved correctly, as the dashed line was a 1nF cap in parallel with the inductor, then I replaced it with the 300pF and it shifted further out.

